# django print value of checked box from HTML form

Tags: html, django, django-views

I have a HTML form that is displaying a table with data. I added checkboxes to the form and now want to take baby steps to print the value of the checked box, when the button named **"test_btn"** on my HTML form is clicked. However, based on the lack of console logs, I know that I am not entering the **get_checked_items function**. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my HTML Form named show.html

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<form method="POST" action=#>
{% csrf_token %}
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Shipment ID</th>
        <th>Load Number</th>
        <th>Booked By</th>
        <th>Pickup City</th>
        <th>Pickup State</th>
        <th>Pickup Date</th>
        <th>Pickup Time</th>
        <th>Destination City</th>
        <th>Destination State</th>
        <th>Trailer Number</th>
        <th>Seal Number</th>
        <th>Primary Driver</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for ship in shipment %}  
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="checks" id="{{ship.id}}" value="{{ship.id}}" />{{ship.id}}</td>
        <td>{{ship.load_number}}</td>
        <td>{{ship.booked_by}}</td>
        <td>{{ship.pickup_city}}</td>
        <td>{{ship.pickup_state}}</td>
        <td>{{ship.pickup_date}}</td>
        <td>{{ship.pickup_time}}</td>
        <td>{{ship.destination_city}}</td>
        <td>{{ship.destination_state}}</td>
        <td>{{ship.trailer_number}}</td>
        <td>{{ship.seal_number}}</td>
        <td>{{ship.primary_driver}}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %} 
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="form-group">
  <button><a href="/showform">Enter New Shipment</a></button>
<div class="form-group">
    <button><a href="/updatedata">Update Data</a></button>
</div>
<input type ="submit" class="btn" value="TESTING" name="test_btn">
</form>
```

Here is my views.py file. I have a couple of print statements in there just to give me some more visibility as to which functions I'm actually entering.

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Shipment

# Create your views here.

    def show(request):
        shipments = Shipment.objects.all()
        print("I am at the show function in views.py")
        return HttpResponse(render(request,"displaydata/show.html",{'shipment':shipments}))
    
    def get_checked_items(request):
        if (request.POST.get("test_btn")):
            print("i made it into the get_checked_items function in views.py")
            checked_item = request.POST.getlist("checks")
            print(checked_item)
        return HttpResponse(render(request,"displaydata/show.html"))
```

And here is my URLS.py for that particular app

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'displaydata'

urlpatterns = [
    path('show/', views.show, name='show'),
    path('get_checked_items/', views.get_checked_items, name='get_checked_items')
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change action attrubute to send data to expected view

```
<form method="POST" action="/get_checked_items/">
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help.